# Xcode 5.1.1 does not stop the application on simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

I just updated the Xcode to 5.1.1. today. And after it when i run my application using the iOS 7.1 simulator. Xcode opened the simulator and displayed the status Running app on Simulator. It took too long to open the application. After that i hit the Stop Button on Xcode to kill the application.

And here the problem invoked. Xcode never stopped or played the application on simulator. I kept hitting the "Play" & "Stop" button. But nothing happened.

So, i restarted my Xcode but the same happened. Then, i restarted my Mac, got the same issue. Does anybody knows why this is happening.

Any guidance will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved this issue. It took really long time to configure what the problem was.

Some time ago, I had edited my etc/hosts file and changed the localhost value to 128.0.0.1.

But found the link:
https://discussions.apple.com/message/24478004#24478004

Which prompt to set localhost default value to 127.0.0.1

To change the value, see the given link:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4488310

Doing this, and restart the Xcode. It did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the simulator. Open the iOS Simulator and choose **iOS Simulator** → **Reset Content and Settings…**. Also clean your project with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> and clean your build folder with <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>.

Also try creating a fresh user account on your computer and try it there.

Comment: I reset the simulator and cleansed the project and build as well but Xcode's "Play" & "Stop" doesn't work at all.(as i mentioned in the question).

Comment: It didn't help me at all. I really need to know why this is happening to me.

Comment: Added another suggestion.

Comment: This isn't an appropriate suggestion. Although i try.

Comment: I meant that it would isolate where the problem is. If it works in the new user account, there is something wrong in your current one, and maybe reinstalling Xcode or deleting preference/cache files could help.

Comment: Yes you're right. But i need more robust solution. Isn't anyone else faced this issue.

Comment: Did it work on the new user account? If so, did you try deleting Xcode preferences or caches, or reinstalling Xcode itself?